# ConfigurationBuilder capture entire JSON object

Tags: c#, json

A little new to this process please bear with me. Using the ConfigurationBuilder() I am
assigning parts of my json file to variables. Please see my example code below. I am able assign the proper value when there is one part of the variable but I am not sure how to capture all of the children

```
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
            var token = config.GetValue<string>("Token");
            var requestBody = config.GetValue<string>("RequestBody:type");
```

Here is my json File

```
    {
     "IsEncrypted": false,
     "Values": {
       "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
       "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    },
    "Token": "myToken",    
    "RequestBody": {
      "path": "myPath",
      "type": "folder",
      "accessibility": "anyone",
      "send_email": true,
      "recipients": [
        "test@gmail.com"
       ],
      "expiry_date": "2023-03-28"
    }
}
```

As expected var token = "myToken"  requestBody ="folder". I want to bring back the entire "RequestBody" as a string but can't figure this out syntatically. Again please don't ding me as I am asking because I am new to this and trying to figure out the syntax.

Comment: "I want to bring back the entire "RequestBody" as a string", Could you pls post the string the way you want ? Striing can look very differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a type and bind configuration section to it. Since [.net-6.0](/questions/tagged/.net-6.0) you can use `ConfigurationKeyName` attribute to match properties names (before that you would need to use exactly the same names for properties and config values):

```cs
public partial class RequestBody
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }
    
    [ConfigurationKeyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    
    [ConfigurationKeyName("accessibility")]
    public string Accessibility { get; set; }
    
    [ConfigurationKeyName("send_email")]
    public bool SendEmail { get; set; }
    
    [ConfigurationKeyName("recipients")]
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    
    [ConfigurationKeyName("expiry_date")]
    public DateTimeOffset ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var requestBody = config.GetSection("RequestBody").Get<RequestBody>();
```